# multiple dialogs - position each offset of each other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using dialogs to send messages to users on my company's intranet. I am currently using a jquery dialog to display the messages.

```
var alerts = data.d;
$.each(alerts, function(index, notifier) {
    var divId = 'div' + index;
    var div = '<div id="' + divId + '">' + notifier.Message + '</div>';
    $('#alertPlaceHolder').append(div);
    $('#' + divId).dialog({
        width: 400,
        height: 250,
        modal: true,
        title: notifier.Title + ' [Alert Id # ' + notifier.AlertId + ']',
        show: 'slide',
        hide: 'explode',
        position: {
            my: "left top",
            at: "left top",
            of: 'window'
        },
        buttons: {
            'Ok': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

If there is more than one message, this currently places each dialog on top of each other. How do I get the dialogs to offset each other by `n`. For example:

[image: Dialog off set]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> my (default: "center") Type: String Defines which position on the
>   element being positioned to align with the target element: "horizontal
>   vertical" alignment. A single value such as "right" will be normalized
>   to "right center", "top" will be normalized to "center top" (following
>   CSS convention). Acceptable horizontal values: "left", "center",
>   "right". Acceptable vertical values: "top", "center", "bottom".
>   Example: "left top" or "center center". **Each dimension can also
>   contain offsets, in pixels or percent, e.g., "right+10 top-25%"**.
>   Percentage offsets are relative to the element being positioned.

So you can define an offset var inside the `.each` and just doing something like

`my: "left top + " + myOffSet` should do the trick.